# patch called return empty

Tags: flutter, patch

I have to make a Patch type call where it has this pattern:

```
{
"description": "string",
"opening_hours": {
  "MON": [{"from": "time", "to": "time"}, {"from": "time", "to": "time"}],
  "TUE": [{"from": "time", "to": "time"}],
    ...
},
"is_on_holiday": "boolean"
```

}

of which I tried has structured it like this in my project: https://pastebin.com/B6dCe5ZW

but I have errors, it does not print any response.body and if I look in debug after the call with 200 it gives me a {} ... while I need to send the example body to the server ("description: ....")
where is that wrong? I double-checked and the data on the call are correct but it seems that they are not passed ... I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.encode` to encode what you are passing to `data`, this is using your pastebin code.

```
async {
    final response = await _provider.patch("$_path/$unitId/accessoryData",
        data: json.encode({
          'description': description,
          'opening_hours': {
            'MON': [
              {'from': from, 'to': to},
              {'from': from, 'to': to}
            ],
 .
.
.
})
```

This is for the code in your post:

```
json.encode(
{
"description": "string",
"opening_hours": {
  "MON": [{"from": "time", "to": "time"}, {"from": "time", "to": "time"}],
  "TUE": [{"from": "time", "to": "time"}],
    ...
},
"is_on_holiday": "boolean"
})
```

Comment: where i put this ?

Comment: Updated my answer